# Opencart search page custom product link structure

Tags: php, opencart

By default, in Opencart, on the search page when I search for a product, the products appear with the following link structure: `sitename/product-name/?search=`, but I want to change this to `sitename/category/subcategory/product-name`

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
            );
```

the 'href' is the line that contains the link structure .

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
            );
```

Comment: do you want to change the product link only in search results or  in all pages (category page, featured module, best sellers module ...)

Comment: hmm only in search page in category page is ok /category/subcategory/product name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function for this a while back and you are free to use it.  The only problem arises when a product belongs to more than one category, in which case the function chooses the deepest level category to generate full path.  If more than one exists at the same depth level it will choose the first match.

Add this function to the end of `/catalog/model/catalog/product.php`:

```
public function getProductCategoryPath ($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(path_id ORDER BY LEVEL ASC SEPARATOR '_') as path 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path USING (category_id)
        WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'
            AND category_id =
            (
                SELECT category_id 
                FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category c 
                LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp USING (category_id) 
                WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' 
                AND cp.level =
                (
                    SELECT max(LEVEL) 
                    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category
                    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path USING (category_id)
                    WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'
                )
                ORDER BY category_id LIMIT 1
            )
        GROUP BY category_id
    ");
    return $query->num_rows ? $query->row['path'] : false;  
}
```

Then revise `catalog/controller/product/search.php` immediately before the block you posted to call the function like this:

```
$path = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductCategoryPath($result['product_id']);
$url = $path ? '&path=' . $path : '';

$this->data['products'][] = array(
```

**Explanation:**

The query in the function first finds all categories that are linked to the product.  Next it finds the the deepest level and selects the first category it encounters which both matches that level and is assigned to the product.  Then it uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to build a path string of the category hierarchy based on the selected category.

In the `search.php` controller we then call this function and if there is a non-empty result, we replace the search url OpenCart with the category path string returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that. This is the href link for link to a product echo

```
$product['href'] <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
```